# Azure Functions dynamic service plan and queue triggers

Tags: azure-functions

I've read that Azure Functions that utilize the dynamic app service plan will scale down to zero instances when there isn't anything to work on. In this state, if you use a queue trigger (either storage or service bus), will an instance be created when something gets pushed onto the queue, or do you need to keep at least one instance running in order to "listen to" or pop things off of the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After registering your queue trigger, the Azure Functions infrastructure monitors your queue for any messages. If the infrastructure detects messages in your queue, it will automatically wake up an instance (if one isn't already awake) to process the messages. Your instance does not have to be awake at the time the queue message is added. This automatic instance initialization is unique to the Dynamic Plan.